# How to view the full size and remove old Google Profile pictures

Tags: google-account, google-account-profile

How do you actually view and delete profile pictures from a Google account? For example, in Google Drive, if I click on the picture of me in the top right corner > click change > under your photos, click the one photo > it shows the current one and all of the old ones, but I’d like the option to view them in full size and delete them. How can this be done? I tried looking in Google Photos and nothing is there.

Note: I sometimes get confused as to which Google product I'm using. I see this picture in Google Drive, but it's also used across all Google products I log in to.

Comment: I suggest that you look for the albums here https://get.google.com/albumarchive/ Be sure to sign in with all your Google accounts if you have more than one.

Answer (score 14):

Google unified the account management system for almost all their products. One of the results of this integration is that the top bar has the same buttons on the top right corner, including the profile photo.

The current profile photo and the old ones could be seen on a "system" album called "Profile photos" which could be found in the Photos tab of Google+ Classic and on "Archived photos" section on [Google About me](https://aboutme.google.com/).

To delete a profile photo,

1. Go to Profile photos album. It will shows thumbnails of the profile photos.
2. Click on the photo, a bigger version will be shown.
3. Click on the More options button (it's on the top right corner) and then Delete photo.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2017, Google plus removed the option to easily go back to the classic system. To see or delete your archived photos;

1. Go to your Google+ Profile
2. Click "about me" (https://aboutme.google.com)
3. Scroll down to see your Album Archive
4. Click "See all" to download or delete your old photos from different Google apps

Comment: No need to take step 1.  Just click the provided link, or immediately go to http://get.google.com/albumarchive which is where step 3 will take you.