# How do I delete my recent google profile picture after I've changed it?

Tags: google-account, profile-picture, google-account-profile

Every time you change your profile picture on Google it saves it, and I would like to know how to delete recent Google profile pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**
You can go to https://get.google.com/albumarchive. Login and then manage old photos and
albums. You can delete them permanently by pressing the more options more options button in the top right corner that looks like three vertical dots. Then press delete.

**References and Additional Links**
[How to view the full size and remove old Google Profile pictures](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95167/how-to-view-the-full-size-and-remove-old-google-profile-pictures)